# DataTable Error: missing } in dom

Tags: datatables

I have datatables with function footercallback and it works well
and I want to add export datatables uses html5 like this

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ]
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;
        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };
        // Total over all pages
        total = api
            .column( 6 )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );
        // Total over this page
        pageTotal = api
            .column( 6, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Update footer
        $( api.column( 6 ).footer() ).html(
            'Rp'+pageTotal +' ( Rp'+ total +' total)'
        );
    }
} );
```

but show error

```
`SyntaxError: missing } after property list
dom: 'Bfrtip',`
```

can you help me?
What I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma after your buttons array:

```
    buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ],
```

You should try out http://jslint.com/ - it's a great resource for verifying Javascript syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a coma after the list, like this:

```
buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ],
```